# String indices must be integers geojson

Tags: python, list, coordinates, geojson

I am trying to extract coordinates from Geojson in Python, when I am trying to extract coordinates from the entire file it is throwing an error "string indices must be integers". But when I am trying to extract single coordinate it runs fine.

Below code gives correct results as [46.931625, -84.52694]

```
import geojson
with open('output.json') as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)
features = gj['features'][0]

geometry = features['geometry']
geometry['coordinates']
```

But When I am trying to run through entire file it throws an error

```
for feature in gj['features']:
    for geometry in feature['geometry']:
            for coordinates in geometry:
                print(geometry['coordinates'])
```

sample data is as follows

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          46.931625,
          -84.52694
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "event": "a",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          46.931725,
          -84.52684
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "event": "a",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me with the error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `feature['geometry']` is a dictionary, so the following line will iterate through keys of that dict:

```
for geometry in feature['geometry']:
```

You are getting that error since `geometry` is a key, such as `"type"`, which is a string. Besides, you don't seem to be using loop variable `coordinates` anywhere in your code.

Try the following instead:

```
for feature in gj['features']:
    print(feature["geometry"]['coordinates'])
```

or better

```
for feature in gj['features']:
    lat, lon = feature["geometry"]['coordinates']
    print("Lat:", lat, "Lon: ", lon)
```

This should result in something like

```
('Lat:', 46.931625, 'Lon: ', -84.52694)
('Lat:', 46.931725, 'Lon: ', -84.52684)
```

Answer (score 0):

features in your sample is the only array object. Loop through features and get the array of coordinates.

Compressed code:

```
print([features['geometry']['coordinates'] for features in gj['features']])
```

This will loop through `gj['features']` and print only the `features['geometry']['coordinates']` for each of the features.

your script would look like this

```
import geojson
with open('output.json') as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

print([features['geometry']['coordinates'] for features in gj['features']])
```